# Centering vertically list items multiline ol

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically center the counter list relative to the elements of the list, I can do it rigidly margin in px, but when changing resolution displays it incorrectly

Here is my HTML

```css
.why-ol {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 26px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  counter-reset: numList;
}

.why-ol li {
  width: 43%;
  margin-right: 44px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.why-ol li span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.why-ol li:before {
  counter-increment: numList;
  content: counter(numList)".";
  float: left;
  left: -26px;
  font: bold 25px sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0073d5;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 999px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  border: 1px solid #0073d5;
  margin: 50px 20px 50px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ol class="why-ol">
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q4tcf7x1/

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified your code.

- Gave the `li` a left margin.
- Positioned the pseudo-element for the `li` relatively, moved it a little more left

Check it yourself.

```css
.why-ol{
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 26px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  counter-reset: numList;
}
.why-ol li {
  position: relative;
  width: 43%;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 44px;
  display: inline-block;;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom:25px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.why-ol li span{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.why-ol li:before {
  counter-increment: numList;
  content: counter(numList)".";
  position: absolute;
  left: -60px;
  font: bold 25px sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0073d5;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 999px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  border:1px solid #0073d5;
  margin: 50px 20px 50px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;;
}
```

```html
<ol class="why-ol">
    <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Hope it answered your question. Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `flex` in `span` and `height:100%` to pseudo element

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q4tcf7x1/2/)**

```css
.why-ol {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 26px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  counter-reset: numList;
}

.why-ol li {
  width: 43%;
  margin-right: 44px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.why-ol li span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex;
}

.why-ol li:before {
  counter-increment: numList;
  content: counter(numList)".";
  float: left;
  left: -26px;
  font: bold 25px sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0073d5;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 999px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  border: 1px solid #0073d5;
  margin: 50px 20px 50px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ol class="why-ol">
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span><br/>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex omnis dolore inventore qui, doloremque atque, architecto quae dolorum obcaecati facere consequatur, ea non ipsum corrupti iste dolorem! Reprehenderit, provident, aut!</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```